# Difference between 'get' and 'get set' in Swift

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I understand that 'get' is used to give instructions on value for the variable 'numberOfWheels' is acquired. However, I do not understand what 'get set' is supposed to achieve in the code below. Does it mean that value can be acquired from the class, enum, or struct AND can also be acquired by a parameter passed on?

```
protocol WheeledVehicle: Vehicle {
  var numberOfWheels: Int { get }
  var wheelSize: Double { get set }
}
```

Comment: It only means that tou can set, that is, write the value. Its not read only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This protocols requires conforming types (classes, structs or enums) to have two properties:

1. `numberOfWheels`, which must provide at least a getter. This means it's either a `let` property, a `var` property, or a computed property with at least a getter (the setter is optional).
2. `wheelSize`, which must provide a getter *and* a setter. This means it has to be either a `var` property, or a computer property with both a getter and a setter.